# pushing back data into 2d vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, 2d-vector

```
vector <int> col(0);
vector<vector<int> > row(0);

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
col.push_back(some integer);

row.push_back(col);
col.clear();
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here? In the `col[]` vector, there is no error, but when I go to the next instruction by debug on line the before last line, just size of `row[]` changes to 1 from 0, but I can't see the values that it should take from the `col[]` vector?

Edit: I tried to put debug screen's screen-shot but reputation thing happened.

Comment: Can you cut and paste the debug text?

Comment: Although inefficient, I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: @GWW If you mean watch screen, I can't.

Comment: What on earth is the `col[]` vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely no problem with your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< int > col(0);
    vector< vector<int> > row(0);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        col.push_back(i);

    row.push_back(col);
    col.clear();

    std::cout << "row size is: " << row.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "row 1st elem size is: " << row[0].size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "col size is: " << col.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
row size is: 1
row 1st elem size is: 10
col size is: 0
```

Which is perfectly expected. Could be a bug in your debugger (it may not show you the actual vector sizes).

Comment: thanks for help. I think you are right. I was using DevCpp, now I created new project with CodeBocks, it works perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @asker Bloodshed Dev-C++ is ancient. Who is still recommending this Windows 95 software in 2014?

Comment: @bames53 the school's IT members :P all computers have it installed :)