# Vector of structs which contains another vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I need to have dynamically allocated space of structs and those structs have to contain another dynamically allocated. If I do it by manual allocation, that would laborious.

So I want to do it through vectors:

```
using namespace std;

struct lol{
    int value;
    vector<int> vekt;
};

vector<lol> vektt;
```

It is logically, that I am going to do it like the code above but I dont know how to do 2 things that I am going to need for my program:

1.iterate through both of them to get `value`s

2.push something into `vekt`( the vector of struct );

I tried something like this for pushing but doesnt work:

```
vektt[0] . vekt . push_back( 2 );
```

So I need to know how to iterate through both of these vectors and how to access members and methods of the vector `vect`.

Comment: read some documentation and/or use the sidebar.

Comment: [How to iterate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409348/iteration-over-stdvector-unsigned-vs-signed-index-variable) ,  [How to push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613246/pushing-back-data-into-2d-vector-in-c)

Comment: really? dont say! maybe I didnt quite understand and because of that came here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Iterating
for (auto &i: vektt)                 // or const auto &i according to requirements
{
    cout << i.value << ", ";
    for (auto j: i.vekt) cout << j << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
// Inserting int to vekt of i-th element of vektt
int a;
vektt[i].vekt.push_back(a);
```

Comment: use `auto&` instead of `auto`

Comment: @M.M or even `const auto&`

Comment: when I use vektt[0] . vekt . push_back( 2 ), it gives me seg fault

Comment: @alik33 You need to ensure there was an item allocated at `vektt[0]`.